# appendix missing in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, apa6

I have a document with apa6 class in which sections are the uppermost heading level. In Lyx I set "Start Appendix here" which sets \appendix in the sorce. Afterwards I define a section. In the rendered document (pdflatex) it reads Appendix A followed by the section name but there is no toc entry.

So my questions are:
Am I missing something? In other posts I read that the toc entries should appear automatically.

I don't know, if it is possibly suppressed by the document class. Does anybody know, if this might be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class `apa6` command `\appendix` redefines `\section` completly and this redefined `\section` does not provide an entry in ToC.

You could patch `\appendix` to patch the redefined `\section`:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd\appendix
  {\xapptocmd\section
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname\ifoneappendix\else~\theappendix\fi\ #1}}
    {}{\InnerPatchFailed}%
  }
{}{\PatchFailed}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text in this example

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd\appendix
  {\xapptocmd\section
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname\ifoneappendix\else~\theappendix\fi\ #1}}
    {}{\InnerPatchFailed}%
  }
{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\appendix
\section{Section in Appendix}
\subsection{Subsection in Appendix}
\Blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I would never have found that solution on my own.